# CSS: Chrome & Safari ignore table-cell heights

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Here's the setup:

```
<div id="container"> <!-- display: table -->
  <div id="row"> <!-- display: table-row -->
    <div id="content1"> <!-- display: table-cell; height: 500px -->
     The content
    </div>
    <div id="content2"> <!-- display: table-cell; height: 500px -->
     The content 2
    </div>
    <div id="content3"> <!-- display: table-cell; height: 500px; overflow: hidden -->
     The content 3, very long
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected behavior: The whole setup shouldn't exceed the height of 500px, so it does in Firefox. However in Chrome and Safari the height values are ignored and the whole setup gets the height of the highest element (content 3).

What's going on? How could I fix this?

**EDIT:** My pasted example also doesn't work in Firefox, no clue why it worked in first place...

[Full example:](http://pastebin.com/J1eb99Ab)

```css
#container {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden
}
#row {
  display: table-row;
  overflow: hidden
}
#content1 {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 500px;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden
}
#content2 {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 500px;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden
}
#content3 {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 500px;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!-- display: table -->
  <div id="row">
    <!-- display: table-row -->
    <div id="content1">
      <!-- display: table-cell; height: 500px -->
      The content
    </div>
    <div id="content2">
      <!-- display: table-cell; height: 500px -->
      The content 2
    </div>
    <div id="content3">
      <!-- display: table-cell; height: 500px; overflow: hidden -->
      The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />The content 3, very long
      <br />

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, row is only used once, so an ID is correct. Also in your link it doesn't work if you fill long content into content3.

Comment: Ah, that's what you are trying to do. Using classes here would be more flexible simply because you might want to add another table or row later. [You can simplify your CSS too](http://jsbin.com/hawibi/3/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table cell height is defined by how much room contents get. If you specify the height, it may be used as min-height.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout

Solution is to use extra div inside the cell.